# Flutter Payement with PayPal

Tags: flutter, paypal

There is no package in flutter for payment with PayPal. So I plain to use the official PayPal API : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/, is it the best solution ?

How manage webhook ? If my backend handle it and respond to me with websocket, is it a good practice ?

Answer (score -1):

maybe this can help: https://pub.dev/packages/paypal#-readme-tab-

now sure

Comment: Package not updated since one year, not linked to any github repository, maybe a dead project :'( !